# MongoDb $addToSet array updating after submitting twice

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose, axios

I have a React-redux-form to add places to a user. Data is sent with axios & the resulting update is console logged.

```js
export const savePlaceToUser = (place, user) => async dispatch => {
  let saved = {};
  saved.userId = user._id;
  saved.placeId = place._id
  const res = await axios.put('/api/place/save', saved);
  console.log(res.data.savedPlace);
}
```

The express js route is as follows.

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = mongoose.model('users');

app.put('/api/place/save', (req, res)=>{
  User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.userId, {
    "$addToSet" : { savedPlace: req.body.placeId}
  }, (err, user)=>{
    err ? res.send(err) : res.send(user)
  })
})
```

And here is the user model.

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  googleId:String,
  userName:String,
  userDp:String, 
  savedPlace: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Place" }]
});

mongoose.model('users', userSchema);
```

On first submit, savedPlace is without the update.
On second submit, the array is updated.

Comment: what do you see in this statement after first attempt `console.log(res.data.savedPlace)` ?

Comment: An array with Id's of previously added places. On submitting again, the array is updated and the new place's id is added to the array.